# Inserting parsed data from one database into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

The following query pulls specific data from an existing database:

```
SELECT (
   SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'File Name') AS File_Name,
  (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable WHERE AttributeName = 'Version Number') AS Version,
  (SELECT 'Category Name') AS Category,
   CAST(LEFT((SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'), 
   CHARINDEX('m', (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'),1 )-2) AS float) AS Value,
   GETDATE() AS Date
FROM SQLTable2
GROUP BY FinalDisposition

UNION

SELECT (
   SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'File Name') AS File_Name,
  (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable WHERE AttributeName = 'Version Number') AS Version,
  (SELECT 'Category Name') AS Category,
   CAST(LEFT((SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'), 
   CHARINDEX('m', (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'),1 )-2) AS float) AS Value,
   GETDATE() AS Date
FROM SQLTable2
GROUP BY FinalDisposition

UNION

SELECT (
   SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'File Name') AS File_Name,
  (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable WHERE AttributeName = 'Version Number') AS Version,
  (SELECT 'Category Name') AS Category,
   CAST(LEFT((SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'), 
   CHARINDEX('m', (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'),1 )-2) AS float) AS Value,
   GETDATE() AS Date
FROM SQLTable2
GROUP BY FinalDisposition
```

This creates a table that looks like this:

```
| File_Name | Version |  Category  | Value |           Date          |
|:---------:|:-------:|:----------:|:-----:|:-----------------------:|
| File1     | 1.0.1   | Duration 1 |  0.04 | 2017-04-17 12:00:00.000 |
| File2     | 1.0.1   | Duration 2 | 0.008 | 2017-04-17 12:00:00.000 |
| File3     | 1.0.1   | Duration 3 | 0.066 | 2017-04-17 12:00:00.000 |
```

As a side note, the reason that value has the "extra" bits is because the format of the original data looks like this: `0.04 minutes`, `0.008 minutes`, and `0.066 minutes`. I wanted to get rid of the minutes and cast as a float.

How can I insert that data into another table (I already have this table in the same column format as the table I want to insert it into).

Or in other words, how can I move that information into an insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Database].dbo.SQLTable3(File_Name,Version,Category,Value,Date)
```

Comment: Have you tried to add this insert line at top of your query?

Comment: well... you could bring this into a #temp table and then do a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM...` I say use a temp table since you are pulling from other servers.

Comment: If you ever add a second row to SQLTable or SQLTable1 this is going to break because your subquery will return more than 1 row.

Comment: see comment to answer below. Putting an insert statement above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    INSERT INTO SQLTable3
    SELECT *
    FROM(   

            SELECT (
               SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'File Name') AS File_Name,
              (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable WHERE AttributeName = 'Version Number') AS Version,
              (SELECT 'Category Name') AS Category,
               CAST(LEFT((SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'), 
               CHARINDEX('m', (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'),1 )-2) AS float) AS Value,
               GETDATE() AS Date
            FROM SQLTable2
            GROUP BY FinalDisposition

            UNION

            SELECT (
               SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'File Name') AS File_Name,
              (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable WHERE AttributeName = 'Version Number') AS Version,
              (SELECT 'Category Name') AS Category,
               CAST(LEFT((SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'), 
               CHARINDEX('m', (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'),1 )-2) AS float) AS Value,
               GETDATE() AS Date
            FROM SQLTable2
            GROUP BY FinalDisposition

            UNION

            SELECT (
               SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'File Name') AS File_Name,
              (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable WHERE AttributeName = 'Version Number') AS Version,
              (SELECT 'Category Name') AS Category,
               CAST(LEFT((SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'), 
               CHARINDEX('m', (SELECT AttributeData FROM SQLTable1 WHERE AttributeName = 'Duration 1'),1 )-2) AS float) AS Value,
               GETDATE() AS Date
            FROM SQLTable2
            GROUP BY FinalDisposition)X
```

Comment: Okay so the original code to create the table works properly, the `SELECT * FROM (code from question) X` generates the same as the code from the question but when you add the insert statement, it gives an error: `Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 9 String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: @Neal you need to make one of the columns bigger. the data that you are trying to insert is bigger than what you are allowing for that column on table SQLTable3. Ex. if your columns is a string varchar(10) and you are trying to insert a string that is 12 characters it will throw that error. you will have to figure out what column it is